# Opening a youtube video with python

Tags: python, youtube, pycharm

I am trying to make a program with Python that will open a youtube video.
The procedure I am trying to apply is:
  type a word(K) in the python prompt
  K reaches the youtube search tab 
  once k is searched, I would like to choose the video to play.

Here an example i found on the internet which is not working:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re

query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({"search_query" : input()})
html_content = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.youtube.com/results?" + query_string)
search_results = re.findall(r'href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode())
print("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + search_results[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run your program it asks for input, do you enter it?

To make it more clear, replace this line:

`query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({"search_query" : input()})`

with this

`query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({"search_query" : input("Type search query and hit enter: ")})`

and then run your program.

With query "hello" I got link to Adele - Hello video.

Comment: I get this error:
line 6, in <module>
   query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({"search_query" : input("Type search query and hit enter:")})
NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined

Comment: That's what i typed:

def song(): 
import urllib.request 
import urllib.parse 
import re 

query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({"search_query" : input("Type search query and hit enter:")}) 
html_content = urllib.request.urlopen("youtube.com/results?" + query_string) 
search_results = re.findall(r'href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode()) print("youtube.com/watch?v=" + search_results[0]) 

song()

Comment: now I can enter the the imput(e.g. Hello), and i get this:

urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748)>

Comment: What is your python version? Why did you change the code? Could you at least try to fromat your text? Keep your imports out of your function definitions.

Your example works for me.
What error did the original example give? When?

Comment: My python version is 3.6.2 run on a Mac. 

-**import urllib.request**
-**import urllib.parse**
-**import re**

-***query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({"search_query" : input("Type search query and hit enter: ")})***

-***html_content = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.youtube.com/results?" + query_string)***

-***search_results = re.findall(r'href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode())***

-***print("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + search_results[0])***

Comment: I still get the same error, ' ssl: certificate failed.

Comment: When? What line throws that error?
Why did you remove `http://www.` from the beginning of your youtube.com addresses?

Comment: I DID insert the _www_ but I dont know why it didn't paste in the comment. 

**Look, I am literally copying and pasting what you suggested with all the remaining code. **
When i run it i get around 3000 character of errors and at the very end i get **[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748)**
_Is there a way in this website I can send you the py. code? At this point I dont thinks it's a coding problem. _

Comment: I believe something is wrong with your Python installation on your Mac. As I don't have Mac I can't be further helpful. **BUT** as you didn't realize that your program was running with the example and was waiting for your input, I suggest taking few steps back and starting with something more simple maybe? In any case, [maybe this link helps you](https://bugs.python.org/issue28150).

It might help if you posted your whole 3000 characters of errors.